# Cloud voice and speech recording [for Android phone Chrome]

Tags: android, web-apps, cloud-storage, audio-recording, phone

Looking for something as simple as a normal online (cloud) voice recorder that works on cheap Android phone Chrome. That is **free** and can store at least ~110 hours of audio (or 1.5h/day), each recording could be as long as ~12mins. [Swear I've tested like fifty or more options but plenty of them can't do even the simplest stuff.]

Important requirements:

- It must work on phones with a (temporary) file storage budget of 0.00 bytes.
- The recording should be as normal-raw as possible. That is, the quality should be that of what other browser-based apps can do as well as having no added "effects" like cancellation etc.
- Literally, it must work (instead of "hang").

Currently I'm using [Trebble.fm](https://trebble.fm) but it's not great because:

1. The playback has no skip. (can only play from front to back... even if you want to hear the last minute)

Also it's:

2. No data-loss prevention whatsoever. (I just lost a 30min recording because it got stuck at 19% while uploading to server.)
3. Security is unknown. Does the webmaster sell/listen to your words?
4. Associated date/s of the recording are not shown. neither duration of recording! (Logging that manually is a pain even if not error-prone.)
5. No foldering (All your are in one folder.)
6. I can't pause the recording and hear last x seconds before continuing.

**Are there better options to Trebble while not requiring a Google/Microsoft account?**

---

Additional shouldhaves and couldhaves [can be found in the previous edit](/revisions/90096/5).